# WooCommerce - disable BACS for one shipping method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I would like to disable wire transfer payment method (bacs gateway) for a specific shipping method. I want customers to pay for the shipping if they select Cash on Delivery payment method but I want them also to get free shipping if they select wire transfer method.

I was able to disable COD if they select free shipping, but was not able to disable wire transfer if they select not-free shipping.

How can I disable BACS for that one particular shipping method?

Answer (score 0):

I already had installed the WooCommerce Custom Payment Gateways plugin. That activates some more gateway options so I was working with it and edited one of it's classes.

The following is my modified version of woocommerce-custom-payment-gateways/class-wc-custom_payment_gateway_5.php

```
<?php
/**
 * WC wcCpg5 Gateway Class.
 * Built the wcCpg5 method.
 */
class WC_Custom_Payment_Gateway_5 extends WC_Gateway_BACS {

/**
 * Constructor for the gateway.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct() {
    global $woocommerce;

    $this->id             = 'wcCpg5';
    $this->icon           = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_wcCpg5_icon', '' );
    $this->has_fields     = false;
    $this->method_title     = __( 'Bacs', 'woocommerce' );

// Load the settings.
$this->init_form_fields();
$this->init_settings();

// Define user set variables
    $this->title        = $this->get_option( 'title' );
    $this->description  = $this->get_option( 'description' );
    $this->instructions = $this->get_option( 'instructions', $this->description );
    $this->enable_for_methods = $this->get_option( 'enable_for_methods', array() );
  // BACS account fields shown on the thanks page and in emails
    $this->account_details = get_option( 'woocommerce_bacs_accounts',
       array(
            array(
               'account_name'   => $this->get_option( 'account_name' ),
               'account_number' => $this->get_option( 'account_number' ),
               'sort_code'      => $this->get_option( 'sort_code' ),
               'bank_name'      => $this->get_option( 'bank_name' ),
               'iban'           => $this->get_option( 'iban' ),
               'bic'            => $this->get_option( 'bic' )
           )
        )
    );

    // Actions
    add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'save_account_details' ) );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_bacs', array( $this, 'thankyou_page' ) );

    // Customer Emails
    add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', array( $this, 'email_instructions' ), 10, 3 );

    // Actions.
    if ( version_compare( WOOCOMMERCE_VERSION, '2.0.0', '>=' ) )
        add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( &$this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
    else
        add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways', array( &$this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
}


/* Admin Panel Options.*/
function admin_options() {
    ?>
    <h3><?php _e('Custom Payment Gateways 5','wcwcCpg5'); ?></h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <?php $this->generate_settings_html(); ?>
    </table> <?php
}

/* Initialise Gateway Settings Form Fields. */
public function init_form_fields() {
$shipping_methods = array();

    if ( is_admin() )
        foreach ( WC()->shipping->load_shipping_methods() as $method ) {
            $shipping_methods[ $method->id ] = $method->get_title();
        }
    $this->form_fields = array(
        'enabled' => array(
            'title'   => __( 'Enable/Disable', 'woocommerce' ),
            'type'    => 'checkbox',
            'label'   => __( 'Enable Bank Transfer', 'woocommerce' ),
            'default' => 'yes'
         ),
        'title' => array(
            'title'       => __( 'Title', 'woocommerce' ),
            'type'        => 'text',
            'description' => __( 'This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'default'     => __( 'Direct Bank Transfer', 'woocommerce' ),
            'desc_tip'    => true,
        ),
        'description' => array(
            'title'       => __( 'Description', 'woocommerce' ),
            'type'        => 'textarea',
            'description' => __( 'Payment method description that the customer will see on your checkout.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'default'     => __( 'Make your payment directly into our bank account. Please use your Order ID as the payment reference. Your order won\'t be shipped until the funds have cleared in our account.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'desc_tip'    => true,
        ),
        'instructions' => array(
            'title'       => __( 'Instructions', 'woocommerce' ),
            'type'        => 'textarea',
            'description' => __( 'Instructions that will be added to the thank you page and emails.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'default'     => '',
            'desc_tip'    => true,
        ),
        'account_details' => array(
            'type'        => 'account_details'
            ),
        'enable_for_methods' => array(
            'title'             => __( 'Enable for shipping methods', 'woocommerce' ),
            'type'              => 'multiselect',
            'class'             => 'chosen_select',
            'css'               => 'width: 450px;',
            'default'           => '',
            'description'       => __( 'If COD is only available for certain methods, set it up here. Leave blank to enable for all methods.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'options'           => $shipping_methods,
            'desc_tip'          => true,
            'custom_attributes' => array(
                'data-placeholder' => __( 'Select shipping methods', 'woocommerce' )
            )
        )
    );
}
    /**
 * Check If The Gateway Is Available For Use
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function is_available() {
    $order = null;

    if ( ! $this->enable_for_virtual ) {
        if ( WC()->cart && ! WC()->cart->needs_shipping() ) {
            return false;
        }

        if ( is_page( wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' ) ) && 0 < get_query_var( 'order-pay' ) ) {
            $order_id = absint( get_query_var( 'order-pay' ) );
            $order    = wc_get_order( $order_id );

            // Test if order needs shipping.
            $needs_shipping = false;

            if ( 0 < sizeof( $order->get_items() ) ) {
                foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
                    $_product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );

                    if ( $_product->needs_shipping() ) {
                        $needs_shipping = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            $needs_shipping = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping', $needs_shipping );

            if ( $needs_shipping ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( ! empty( $this->enable_for_methods ) ) {

        // Only apply if all packages are being shipped via local pickup
        $chosen_shipping_methods_session = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );

        if ( isset( $chosen_shipping_methods_session ) ) {
            $chosen_shipping_methods = array_unique( $chosen_shipping_methods_session );
        } else {
            $chosen_shipping_methods = array();
        }

        $check_method = false;

        if ( is_object( $order ) ) {
            if ( $order->shipping_method ) {
                $check_method = $order->shipping_method;
            }

        } elseif ( empty( $chosen_shipping_methods ) || sizeof( $chosen_shipping_methods ) > 1 ) {
            $check_method = false;
        } elseif ( sizeof( $chosen_shipping_methods ) == 1 ) {
            $check_method = $chosen_shipping_methods[0];
        }

        if ( ! $check_method ) {
            return false;
        }

        $found = false;

        foreach ( $this->enable_for_methods as $method_id ) {
            if ( strpos( $check_method, $method_id ) === 0 ) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( ! $found ) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return parent::is_available();
}


}
```

with this you have the option to enable bacs for shipping methods